# oil light flash while pressing gas

Tags: oil, hyundai, fuel-consumption, crankshaft, oil-pressure

I have Hyundai i30 2008, i have changed crankshaft sensor 1 week ago.
two days ago i start hearing some noise from motor while in idle and also while moving.
Today the check engine light turned on and the oil light flashes only when i'm pressing gas, if i don't press gas its off.
even if i press gas while im in "N" gear it turn on.
I also noticed that the fuel consumption of the car is becoming bad.
any idea what might be the issue?

Note:
I have checked the engine oil its less than full, i added more oil but still same issue.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You sure you didn't displace (or partially displace) the sensor wires going to the oil pressure sending unit (or anything else for that matter)? You might want to check your work and see (if to verify for no other reason).

Comment: I don't know, I will check tomorrow with the mechanician who changed the crankshaft, but its 1 week ago, i assume if he forgot to connect something it should appear immediately. Do you think it's safe to drive it to the mechanician?

Comment: No clue on how safe it is to drive it. I was suggesting something might not be reattached all the way. If you've never experienced an issue like this before and there was something done to the vehicle very recently, that's where you start looking.

Comment: i agree with your theory. Will check tomorrow. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Ok problem solved by cleaning the oil pan and the thing inside it i guess its a filter or something.

Comment: When cleaning the oil pan and the mesh filter on the oil pickup, what was blocking it (sealant goo, metal etc)?

Due to having decreased oil pressure you may have suffered damage to some engine parts. It may be worth doing another oil change to see if there is metal in the oil.